# HYBRID VLAN in Huawei Switches

Tags: vlan

I know how the trunk and access ports vlans are behave.
I found something in huawei switches that is called hybrid vlan. what is hybrid vlan and how its behave?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's not a hybrid vlan, it's a hybrid port. You have access port = one untagged vlan, you have trunk port = multiple tagged and at most one untagged vlan.

And then you have hybrid - multiple untagged vlan. But then you need to somehow know where to put each incoming frame - that is done on per-frame basis based on MAC address/IP address/protocol/ports/etc. Outgoing frame is always sent untagged.

Keywords for you: IP based VLANs, protocol based VLANs, MAC based VLANs